# Target first and last article on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm helping a student out here. They have templates that contain an article with some anchor tags. These anchor tags represent "move up, move down, and remove".

These articles will be dynamically changing location.

What I am looking for is this: When an article is first on the page, the "Move Up" anchor should be removed. If an article is in the bottom/last position, the "Move Down" anchor should be removed.

If the article is in a middle position, all anchors must be available.

I know I can apply classes to the first and last articles on the page, but how can I specifically target those articles without them being in a list.

```
<script type="text/template" id="message-edit-item-template">
##    $(".actions").first().children().remove(".move-up")
##    $(".actions").last().children().remove(".move-down");
##  ^ this is just me experimenting. I added the move-up and move-down classes to the anchors below, but they can be removed if not needed
<article class="well" data-message-id="<%= data.id %>">
    <div class="message">
        <div class="highlight clearfix">
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" data-remove="true" class="pull-right" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Remove</a>
                <a href="#" data-move-up="true" class="pull-right move-up" title="Move Up"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> Move Up</a>
                <a href="#" data-move-down="true" class="pull-right move-down" title="Move Down"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> Move Down</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="<%= data.title %>" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" class="form-control"><%= data.message %></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
</script>
```

Comment: Are all the `<article>` elements siblings of each other?

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS for this.

```
.actions:first-child .move-up, .actions:last-child .move-down {
   display: none;
}
```

When you append or prepend new elements, your browser will show/hide the elements automatically based on if they match the CSS selector.

See: [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

Answer (score 1):

What about hide/show?

If you need the buttons to apper again when the articles dynamically change their positions, then hide the buttons instead of remove - there's no reason to remove them.

```
your_function_to_change_dynamically_articles_positions(){
  // some code...
  $(".move-up, .move-down").hide();
  $(".move-up:not(:first)").show();   
  $(".move-down:not(:last)").show();
}
```

**[updated JSfiddle]**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfj8pc8k/)

```
$(".move-up").click(function(){
    var $parent = $(this).closest('article');
    $parent.insertBefore($parent.prev()); 
    showHide(); 
});

 $(".move-down").click(function(){
    var $parent = $(this).closest('article');
    $parent.insertAfter($parent.next());
    showHide(); 
});

$(".remove").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('article').remove();
    showHide();
});

function showHide(){
    $(".move-up, .move-down").show();
    $(".move-up:first").hide();   
    $(".move-down:last").hide();
}

showHide();
```

Comment: Looks good! I will only change the name showHide to fixNavigation.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different for fixNavigation() could be reused later on

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  fixNavigation();
});

function fixNavigation() {
  $('a.pull-right').show();
  $('.well:first a.move-up').hide();
  $('.well:last a.move-down').hide();
}
```